# EReadError "Invalid property value" runtime error in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

When I open a form in Delphi XE4 IDE, there is no error message. However at runtime it is throwing strange error messages such as:

```
Exception class EReadError with message 'Invalid property value'. 
Exception class EReadError with message 'Error reading Chart1.Color: 
Invalid property value'.
```

The form contains a TChart (TTeeChart). The stored property value is "Color = clWindow", which seems completely valid. If I copy/paste this TChart control into a blank project, the properties are the same, however at runtime there is no error.

I tried to remove the line with "Color = clWindow" from the dfm file. In this case I do not get an error message, but the TChart is not visible at runtime. (Even though it is visible at design-time. The color is shown as TBtnFace)

Then, if I resize the form a bit (this causes ExplicitWidth/Height properties to be added), I get the following errors:

```
Exception class EReadError with message 'Property ExplicitWidth does not exist'. 
Exception class EReadError with message 'Error reading Chart1.ExplicitWidth: 
Property ExplicitWidth does not exist'.
```

(I have another form in the project that is also using TChart, and none of these problems occur with it.)

Any ideas what is causing this problem? It seems very strange.

Comment: It sounds like your version of TeeChart was designed for a different version of Delphi than you're using. What happens with a brand new chart control and replicating its properties?

Comment: Yes you are right. My uses clause looked like this: "Series, Chart...  VclTee.TeeGDIPlus, VCLTee.TeEngine, VCLTee.TeeProcs". So part was not referencing the correct units, I didn't notice that.